# How to remove padding next to a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have added a custom button to the navigation bar's custom right bar button item as shown in the image.

I'm want to be able to remove the space after the button so that it touches the right edge of the screen but couldn't find a solution even after searching. If someone could mention how, would be great.

This is the code I'm using

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 60, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testButtonControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aBarButtonItem;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new view, add button and everything else you want and add it to the titleView as shown.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [self titleView];
}

- (UIView *)titleView {
    CGFloat navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width = 0.95 * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, navBarHeight)];
..
// please add what you need here
....
}
```

Comment: I use *another* button as the container view if I want to expand the tappable area as well.

Answer (score 17):

You can add a fixed space element with a negative width (I know, this sounds like a hack, but it works):

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 60, 44);
UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testButtonControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *spaceFix = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:NULL];
spaceFix.width = -5;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[spaceFix, aBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: Too bad it seems you cannot set a negative width in Interface Builder in Xcode 5.

Comment: This worked perfectly. When I was adding a right UIBarButtonItem with a custom view, it leaved a weird space right to it... I can't tell why

Comment: any way to use the negative space to decrease the space between the buttons? They seem to not be affected if I place another of it between them

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you subclass `UINavigationBar` or override its methods via category.

Comment: Can you explain how to after I subclass it or after i use category. I know how to do both but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a UIView then add inside it your button with x=spaceWidth y = 0.

look at the below code for the right item (this is inside UINavigationItem category)

1 -

`UIView *_rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
    [_rightView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];//debug color`

2-

```
    UIButton *aLeftButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];

   //...//

    aLeftButton.frame = CGRectMake(-15, 0, 44, 44);//in your case +15
    [aLeftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:buttonName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aLeftButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[buttonName stringByAppendingString:@"Selected"]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [aLeftButton setAdjustsImageWhenDisabled:NO];
    [aLeftButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];

    [aLeftButton addTarget:theSender action:aSelector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_rightView addSubview:aLeftButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *aBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_rightView];
    [leftBarButtonsItem addObject:aBarButton];`
```

3

`self.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonsItem;`